# Must continuous $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ function tend to zero at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations, weak-derivatives

Here, $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the standard Sobolev spaces for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ functions whose weak derivative belongs to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2).$

My question in the title comes from calculus of variations. It is usually the case that a minimizer of some given energy functional defined on $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is known to be continuous (or even $C^2(\mathbb{R}^2))$. I want to know the behavior of this minimizer at infinity.

If $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2),$ then is known $\liminf_{|x| \to \infty} u(x) = 0.$ But it cannot say $\limsup_{|x| \to \infty} u(x) = 0$ since counterexamples exist.

If we assume $u \in H^{1+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for some $\epsilon > 0,$ then the classical Morrey's inequality can imply uniform H\"older continuity of $u.$ So we can conclude $\limsup_{|x| \to \infty} u(x) = 0$ via proof by contradiction.

So my problem is about the case $\epsilon = 0.$ That is, when 
$$u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap C(\mathbb{R}^2),$$
is it true that
$$\limsup_{|x| \to \infty} u(x) = 0?$$

Using proof by contradiction, I think this should be true. Here is my non-rigorous argument.

> Assume not, then there are $\epsilon > 0$ and $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|x_n| \to \infty$ and $|u(x_n)| \geq 2\epsilon.$ By the continuity, there is $r_n > 0$ such that $|u(x)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $x \in B(x_n, r_n).$
>   Since $u \in L^2, r_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$
>   **I think non-rigorously that** 
>   $$ \int_{B(x_n, r_n)} |\nabla u|^2 \gtrsim \int_{B(x_n, r_n)} (\frac{\epsilon}{r_n})^2 = \epsilon^2$$
>   for large $n$ and
>   $$
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\nabla u|^2 \geq \sum_{n\,\text{is large}} \int_{B(x_n, r_n)} |\nabla u|^2.
> $$
>   So they imply a contradiction  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\nabla u|^2 = \infty$

I appreciate any discussion.

**Edit**: How about $u$ is additionally assumed to be $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ or even $C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)?$ Is there any proof or counterexample?

Comment: If $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $\lim_{|x|\to +\infty}u(x)=0$. So... can you not consider your $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ on a curve where the limit doesn't go to zero and derive a contradiction?

Comment: Interesting idea! I will give it a try. I am thinking how to verify a restriction of $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ function on a smooth curve is a $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ function.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that works even if $\gamma$ is arc length parametrized. I think at most you can say that these integrals are finite for 'almost every' curve (as in Fubini-Tonelli theorem) but that's not good enough

Comment: In fact, functions in $H^{s}(\mathbb{R})$ vanish at infinity iff $s>1/2$ (because then $H^s$ embeds into $L^{\infty}$ and smooth compactly supported functions are dense in $H^s$).   So we would need the 1D traces of functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to belong to $H^s$ for some $s>\frac{1}{2}$, but instead they only belong to $H^{1/2}$. If the function belongs to $H^{1+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ then the argument works, but you already pointed out these functions vanish at infinity. So maybe this strengthens the evidence that for $H^1$ it doesn't work.

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa Thanks for your idea and discussion. My original problem is solved now. That problem comes from the proof of Corollary 1.1 in this paper (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6544/aa99a8). I ask one of the author how to verify the vanishing behavior of the minimizer so that they can apply the radial symmetry result of Li Yi and Wei Ming Ni yesterday. And he answer it with the use of the well-known local boundedness theorem of De Giorgi (see, e.g., Theorem 4.1 of Qing-Lin's Courant Lecture Notes) which means one needs to use the elliptic equation for the minimizer.

Comment: So my problem proposed here maybe inappropriate.

Comment: I think the question is still interesting on it own, a counterexample definitely exists somewhere but I wouldn't know where to find it, most likely it's isn't obvious to construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not hold for general functions $u \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, even if they are assumed to be smooth.
The reason lies in the following lemma:

Let $N \ge 2$. Then for any $x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}, \; \epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ there exists a radial smooth function $u_{k}$ such that:

1. $u_{k}(x_{k})=1$
2. $u_{k}(x)=0$ for $|x-x_{k}|>\delta$
3. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} |\nabla{u_{k}}|^2 \le \epsilon$

Now choose a sequence of points $x_{k}$ going to infinity, choose corresponding
$\delta_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $\epsilon_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$.

Let $u=\sum_{n} u_{n}$.

Then $u \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.

But for any $r>0$ we find some point $x_{r}$ with $|x_{r}|>r$ such that $u(x_{r})=1$.

Comment: How do you keep the $L^2$ norm of the gradient small (3) when the support of $u_k$ is becoming smaller and smaller (2), and $u_k(x_k)=1$?

Comment: Right, I agree, I was getting confused with the $L^{\infty}$ norms for which it is obviously not possible. But for the $L^2$ norms and $N\geq 2$ (critical /subcritical exponent) then it does work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be **not** a general property for functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2) \cap C(\mathbb{R}^2)$ because I find the following remark from [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780857292261).

[image]