# $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap C^1 \Rightarrow u$ vanishes at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)\cap C^1 $, where $H^1$  is the Hilbert-Sobolev space. Is it true that the limit of $u$ at infinity in any direction is 0?

Comment: Be careful with notation. To many of us $C^1_0$ denotes the space of $C^1$ functions with compact support. Limit $0$ at infinity is quite weaker.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $N=1$ it is true that these functions vanish at infinity.

Assume $f \in H^1 \cap C^1$ but does not vanish at infinity. Then there exists some $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ of points going to infinity such that $f(x_n) > 2\epsilon$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

On the other hand, since $f \in L_2$ we know that $f(y_n) < \epsilon$ for another sequence $(y_n)$ satisfying $x_n < y_n < x_{n+1}$.

This implies a contradiction to $f'\in L_2$:

$$\|f\|_{H^1}^2 \ge \|f'\|_{L^2} \ge \sum_{n} | \int_{x_n}^{y_n} f'(x) dx \; | > \sum_{n} \epsilon = \infty$$

However, for $N>1$ it turns out that we can construct a sequence of radial smooth $\epsilon$-bumps that are in $H^1$ but are obviously not vanishing at infinity.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. But can you maybe explain what are $\epsilon-$ bumps exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand.

Comment: Tried to construct a counterexample today, but succeeded only for N>2. Is it possible that the statement is true for N = 2?

Comment: No, there also is a counterexample for $N=2$. This is due to a lemma I discussed in another question. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687484/must-continuous-h1-mathbbr2-function-tend-to-zero-at-infinity/3689355#3689355

Comment: Where is this lemma from? You didn't prove it in your question. I ran into a problem trying to prove it for N = 2.

Comment: @yonatan I just stumbled upon your question by coincidence. I think the idea was to choose a one-dimensional function $\phi$ with $\phi(t) = 1$ around $0$ and $\phi(t) = 0$ outside of a small interval and then consider $u(x) = \phi(\|x\|^{1/m})$ for large $m$. Sorry I can't help you further, I haven't looked at these things in ages. Maybe you can post your proof for $N>2$ and get help here

Comment: @yonatan https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384782/decay-of-h1-mathbbrn-functions?rq=1 also mentions that it only holds for $n=1$

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Although, the construction there isn't a continuous function. Thus, I think the first answer to the question you mentioned answers my question. It is basically  what I did.